# Codeigniter resize issue after transferring server, everything except is looking good

Tags: php, gd, image-resizing

Following is the detail about Server, GD library and image. Everything is fine but image re sizing is not working. Tried a lot of solutions but no luck

```
 print_r(gd_info());
    Array
    (
        [GD Version] => bundled (2.1.0 compatible)
        [FreeType Support] => 1
        [FreeType Linkage] => with freetype
        [T1Lib Support] => 1
        [GIF Read Support] => 1
        [GIF Create Support] => 1
        [JPEG Support] => 1
        [PNG Support] => 1
        [WBMP Support] => 1
        [XPM Support] => 1
        [XBM Support] => 1
        [JIS-mapped Japanese Font Support] => 
    )
    print_r(getimagesize('/var/www/testing/uploads/images/eric.jpg'));
    Array
    (
        [0] => 200
        [1] => 200
        [2] => 2
        [3] => width="200" height="200"
        [bits] => 8
        [channels] => 3
        [mime] => image/jpeg
    )

    Array
    (
        [image_library] => gd2
        [source_image] => /var/www/testing/uploads/images/eric.jpg
        [create_thumb] => 1
        [maintain_ratio] => 
        [width] => 500
        [height] => 800
    )



    $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
    $config['source_image'] = '/var/www/testing/uploads/images/eric.jpg';
    $config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
    $config['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;
    $config['width'] = 500;
    $config['height'] = 800;

    $this->load->library('image_lib');
    $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
    $this->image_lib->resize();
    $this->image_lib->clear();
    if (!$this->image_lib->resize()) {
      echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
    }
    die();
```

Error:

> Your server does not support the GD function required to process this
>   type of image.

It was working fine on previous server but not now. any idea

Answer (score 0):

Do you have GD-support while installing PHP? In Windows, you'll include the GD2 DLL `php_gd2.dll` as an extension in `php.ini`.

Please refer to this link for more details:  http://php.net/manual/en/image.installation.php

For Ubuntu (and Debian) Linux comes with the package called php5-gd. Just type the following command to install this module:

```
# apt-get install php5-gd
```

OR

```
$ sudo apt-get install php5-gd
```

Comment: its linux based server. Still there is need to add this dll file?

Comment: I am checking, will let you know soon

Comment: Is this a separate package for GD library or GD library itself,  as I have mentioned in question the first print() is for GD library information. Anything else I can try?

Answer (score 0):

Everything was fine, code was creating thumb as create_thumb option was true therefore it was not effecting the original image.

I was using this code for dynamic out and found that php 5.4 and later is not supporting "dynamic_output" for image_lib. For this I found solution.

https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/issues/2132